# Error on event listener in view.

Tags: extjs

file custom.js

```
Ext.define('BookApp.view.Customs', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
requires:['BookApp.controller.MainController'],
    xtype: 'customs',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        bind: {
            title: '{name}'
        },
        region: 'west',
        html: '<ul>...</ul>',
        width: 250,
        split: true,
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Button',
            handler: 'onClickButton'
        }]
    },{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items:[{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '<h2>Content ...</h2>'
        }]
    }]
});
```

I have controller MainController

```
Ext.define('BookApp.controller.MainController', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],
 //alias!!!!
    alias: 'controller.main',

    onClickButton: function () {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure?', 'onConfirm', this);
    },

    onConfirm: function (choice) {
        if (choice === 'yes') {
           console.log('ALALA')
        }
    }
});
```

but when i click on button  with property :

```
tbar: [{
                text: 'Button',
                handler: 'onClickButton'
            }]
```

Error :
  **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: I have just run this code generated from the Sencha cmd app and it works fine, the only differences I can see from the example code and yours (apart from app name) is the change of the name of the main controller. ExtJs's loader follows a particular naming convention for loading files, so your controller may not be loading correctly, which would explain the error you are getting. If you would like to name your file Custom.js you should rename the class name and all references to it too. See [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/application_architecture/view_controllers.html

All that was wrong was that you were extending `Ext.app.Controller` instead of `Ext.app.ViewController`

Here is a slightly simplified version excluding the `viewModel` binding

```
//app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'BookApp',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('BookApp.view.Customs', {
            fullscreen: true
        });
    }
});

....
controller/MainController.js
Ext.define('BookApp.controller.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',

    onClickButton: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure?', 'onConfirm', this);
    },

    onConfirm: function(choice) {
        if (choice === 'yes') {
            console.log('ALALA');
        }
    }
});

.....
view/view.Customs.js
Ext.define('BookApp.view.Customs', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'customs',
    controller: 'main',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'testPanel',
        region: 'west',
        html: '<ul>...</ul>',
        width: 250,
        split: true,
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Button',
            handler: 'onClickButton'
        }]
    }, {
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: '<h2>Content ...</h2>'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gdu